# Python NDB: pass variable as parameter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nameerror

When I run the following code

```
class Userx(ndb.Model):
  username = ndb.StringProperty()
  password = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class adduser(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
          user=self.request.get("email")
          o=Userx(parent=ndb.Key("users","key"),password="123",username=user)
          o.put()
```

I get the error message

```
o=Userx(parent=ndb.Key("users","key"),password="123",username=user)
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on my part. The *user* variable is quite well-defined. We would need more code & the complete traceback to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with that Code Sample, maybe the problem is caused by another part? Indirectly maybe? For example, the following code, which is similar to yours, runs without any problem.

```
class myc1:
    def __init__(self,y=0,q=1,t="Spam Eggs"):
        print y,q,t

class myc2:
    def get(self):
        name1 = "Sweeney Todd"
        myobj1 = myc1(q=5,t=name1)


myobj2 = myc2()
myobj2.get()
```

outputs `0 5 Sweeney Todd`

Can you post more of your code?

(p.s I cannot write this as a comment since I don't have sufficient privilege)

Comment: thank you its working now :D

import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class Book(ndb.Model):
    title=ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        title="my title"
        obj=Book(parent=ndb.Key("Books","key"),title=title)
        obj.put()
        self.response.write("it's working")




application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)